# Spring Security 6.0 returns a 403 error when called using a post request with axios but works fine in postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, axios

I'm trying to get back my JWT token from spring security after Auth request, works perfectly fine in postman and generates a token, but when I try Calling it using React axios, I get a 403 Response, this problem only happens with post requests.

Server: Spring Boot localhost:8080

Web: React.js + Axios localhost:3000

Spring security CORS config:

```
 @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Sprig Controllers in question:

```
    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(
            @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.authenticate(request));
    }

    @GetMapping("/hi")
    public ResponseEntity<String> hi(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("hi"); //just to test
    }
```

My axios Function:

```
 const sendLoginRequest = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        let session_url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/authenticate';
        let username = 'notAnEmail@gmail.com';
        let password = 'notAPassword';

        axios.post(session_url, {username,password}
        ).then(function(response) {
            console.log('Authenticated: '+response.data);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error on Authentication');
        });

        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/hi")
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    }
```

Here is the response in localhost:3000
[403 Error for post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGyaN.png)
[Get works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc9WJ.png)

Console Logs:
[Spring console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcX6a.png)

Postman for comparaison:
[Postman Results for comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg0hk.png)

I know there is a very similar thread to this but none of the answers there worked for me

I've tried multiple solution from rewriting my spring security configs multiple times, to all of the changes recommended in other posts such as setting `setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost"))` but that just gave a new error

Comment: And where are your console logs and your spring boot debug logs because i assume you read them before you asked here. Voted to close missing all debugging information

Comment: For the logs since there wasn't anything special, I forgot to mention them, but I'm getting the normal spring/hibernate logs that you get when there is no error or warning, so a basic select query

Comment: @Yassine please fix your question as it is unclear. The postman picture claiming to be working is for another url `/register` while the react app fails for another url `authenticate`. This is misleading info to understand what is happening

Comment: Thanks for notifying me about the screen shot, I used the wrong file by accident, as for the problem when trying to access  `/api/v1/auth/authenticate` using axios it returns a 403 error this seems to only apply to post methods, and can't be replicated using postman, hope this explains it more clearly since English isn't my first language

Comment: Always include logs, i dont ask for debug logs to get your interpretation of the logs. I ask because i want to see what is actually happening. Always include logs in every future question and people will stop asking for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your postman call which works has the following request body sent

[image]

This means you need to adapt your react code into

```
    let username = 'notAnEmail@gmail.com';
    let password = 'notAPassword';

    let requestBody = { email: username, password: password};  // <--------

    axios.post(session_url, requestBody  // <----------
    ).then(function(response) {

    .....
```

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work at first, but after modifying it to ` axios.post(session_url, {
                "email":"TimApple@uir.ac.ma",
                "password":"test"
            }
        ).then(function(response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response. Data));` it seems to work now, thank you so much